# Detect when uib-popover is being opened and being closed?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've been playing with the [uib-popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#popover) and can't figure out how to detect when the popover is being shown or being closed.  It doesn't seem to have the events like "shown.bs.open/hidden" that exist for regular bootstrap popover.

Is there a way to do this I am missing?

The showing of the popover itself is being shown on click, but it's apparently always not visible at that point whether it's open or closed.  Note that I am appending to the body.

thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `popover-is-open` subdirective

From the docs

> popover-is-open  (Default: false) - Whether to show the popover.

Note that this subdirective applies a watcher

> This setting has an angular $watch listener applied to it.

Here's how to use it

```
<button uib-popover="I am activated manually" 
        popover-is-open="isOpen2"
        type="button" class="btn btn-default">
  Toggle popover
</button>
```

And you can initialize it in you controller

```
$scope.isOpen2 = false; // or true
```

Here's a [demo plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/DJotkvOr51brqUBtlBYG?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  How would this work when you have an indeterminant number of popovers on the page (and appended to the body)?  You'd know the particular uib-popover element that got clicked, and in my case I know the specific classinfo so that I can identify a particular popup with its source element... can you have isOpen2 be a hashtable and then tie popover-is-open to isOpen2[some-identifier]?

Comment: `isOpen2` is just some variable bound to scope, you can have many of these inside some data structure (like an array) that will bind to how many popovers as you like. `can you have isOpen2 be a hashtable and then tie popover-is-open to isOpen2[some-identifier]`, not really, but you can work something similar using `ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj"` and then, `popover-is-open="key"`

Comment: That's interesting.  Things are already using an ng-repeat to generate a table that includes other stuff... so if you're doing ng-repeat="foo in fooCollection" for a table,  and have an indicator field on foo for it - like foo.myPopoverIsOpen - then foo.myPopoverIsOpen would be watched?  I'll see about trying that out.